# Error when overriding common field (included field) in a ballerina record

Tags: ballerina

I'm getting an error when trying to override a common field (included field) in one record with a different type in ballerina. Please refer to the below code.

```ballerina
type Vehicle record {
    string color;
    string fuel;
};

type Car record {
    *Vehicle;
    FuelType fuel; // Getting error here
};

type FuelType record  {
    boolean petrol;
    boolean diesel;
};
```

I have two records named `Vehicle` and `Car`, where `Car` includes `Vehicle`. When I override the common field `fuel` from `string` type to a `record` type `FuelType`, I get the following error:

> included field 'fuel' of type 'string' cannot be overridden by a field of type 'FuelType': expected a subtype of 'string'.

However, when I override it with an enum `FuelTypeEnum`, there is no error. Why am I getting two different behaviors?

```ballerina
type Car record {
    *Vehicle;
    FuelTypeEnum fuel; // No error here
};

enum FuelTypeEnum {
    petrol,
    diesel
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, we require overriding fields to use a type, that is a subtype of the overridden field's type. Therefore, the type of `fuel` in `Car` has to be a subtype of `string`. i.e. the type of `fuel` in the included record (`Vehicle` here) will have to be the broader (super) type.

In the second case, an enum is a union of string constants. i.e. The above `FuelTypeEnum` enum is equivalent to,

```ballerina
const petrol = "petrol";
const diesel = "diesel";
type FuelTypeEnum petrol|diesel;
```

Therefore, `FuelTypeEnum` is a subtype of a `string`. Therefore, we can use that to override the field type.

Answer (score 0):

We can also define the `FuleTypeEnum` as a union of singleton types without explicitly defining consts.

```
type FuelType "petrol"|"diesel";

type Vehicle record {
    string color;
    FuelType fuel;
};

type Car record {
    *Vehicle;
};
```